# Disable specific USB ports on RHEL 6

Tags: rhel, mount, usb

I need to disable only 4 of 8 USB ports on my workstation. Unfortunately BIOS doesn't allow me to disable single USB port so I need to do this in RHEL 6. Then, I need to configure which of the allowed ports are restricted to keyboard and mouse only and which ones restricted only to usb storage. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: uff. Needing to plug in new USB devices in an end-of-live RHEL? Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

> hen, I need to configure which of the allowed ports are restricted to keyboard and mouse only and which ones restricted only to usb storage. Is it possible to do this?

No, USB doesn't work like that. You can try to make your software stack not mount USB mass storage devices that aren't at the right bus position , but that's pretty far from the USB side. Also, with a RHEL that old, I'm not sure how to even approach that.

Especially, nothing stops a single USB device to have multiple "subdevices" – for example, it's very common that USB sound cards or headsets are both an USB audio class device as well as a HID device to enable buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And is it possible to disable automount only on a specific bus? or disable only usb-storage?

Comment: as said, for your old OS I wouldn't know how. Technically, it's all open source software that you can modify yourself.